# Create local table and foreign table from the same SQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to build a set of PostgreSQL databases that derive from a separate structure definition. The structure is defined as a set of `.sql` files that will be imported using [`docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres#initialization-scripts) during start.

One of the databases will have regular tables that are created e.g. like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data."origin" (
    origin_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text UNIQUE
);
```

Another database needs to be connected to this one using [foreign tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createforeigntable.html) that should have the same structure, e.g.

```sql
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE data."origin" (
    origin_id serial,
    name text
)
    SERVER localdb
    OPTIONS (schema_name 'data', table_name 'origin');
```

So the question is, whether there is an elegant way to use the original `.sql` files from the first database to construct the second one as well.

The only way that we have in mind is to fiddle with `sed` or similar magic during the image build to add the `FOREIGN` and the `SERVER …` stuff in there, remove the `PRIMARY KEY` etc. This will most likely break sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd try to get a list of tables from the .sql file (or directly from the server to which you applied the .sql file), then feed that list of names to `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA ... LIMIT TO (...)`.  That seems less error prone than what you are envisioning.